# Programmatically adjusting d3 brush with animation

Tags: animation, d3.js

How can a D3 brush be programmatically adjusted from extent to extent? Can it be done so it appears to be animated rather than just instantly snapping to a final extent?

For example:

```
[0,0] to [0,100]
```

Extent just expanding to the right.

Comment: Could you please post your code, or complete example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  d3.select('body').transition()
      .call(brush.extent([0, 100]))
      .call(brush.event);
```

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6216724

Comment: There's a problem with this, brush.extent() called from on('brush') will not reflect the changing extent shown during the transition.

Comment: Could you post an example isolating the problem?